# how to get html of xslt file using altova xmlspy?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml, dtd and xslt files describing an order with some items.
How can I get the out put of xslt as a html file using altova xmlspy?

Answer (score 0):

link the xml file with your xslt file.You can add this after the xml declaration

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="yourxsl.xsl"?>
```

then run the xml file by altova xmlspy. you will get a output html file.

Comment: I don't know how to run it there is  no run button

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="employee.xsl"?>
<employees>
 <employee>
  <firstName>Scott</firstName>
  <lastName>Adams</lastName>
 </employee>
</employees>

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
- <xsl:template match="employee">
- <b>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="firstName" /> 
  </b>
- <b>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="lastName" /> 
  </b>
  </xsl:template>
- <xsl:template match="lastName">
- <i>
  <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
  </i>
  </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>